# Text game board display

Tags: c++, game

I have a game that consists of

- Four countries each has four soldiers
- board that has 24 places to step on.
- Each turn a random dice lands a solider from each team on a place(number) on the board according to the output of the dice.
- After the turn ends the games display the current position of each soldier from each team.

I wonder if there is another easier way to get the output as shown in the linked image. The current routine is 2680 lines long.

If a soldier is on a space on the board, it prints the soldier.  Otherwise it prints the space number.

[image]

---

```
bool PlayBo::ShowBo()
{
    cout << "                France";
    cout << endl;

    if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "                g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "              g2g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "              g3g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "              g4g1";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "            g3g2g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "            g4g3g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "            g4g2g1";
        cout << endl;
    }           
    if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "          g4g3g2g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "                g2";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "              g3g2";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "              g4g2";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "            g4g3g2";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "                g3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "              g4g3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
    {
        cout << "                g4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
    {
        cout << "                  ";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    //space 200
    if (b1->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                g4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (y1->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                r2";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (r3->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 200)
    {
        cout << "                r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "                GS";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 6
    if (b1->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 6)
    {
        cout << "              r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "              06";     
    }   
    //space 7
    if (b1->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  b3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (b4->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (g2->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (y2->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  y3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (y4->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (r1->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 7)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  07";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 5                                                                       
    if (b1->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 5)
    {
        cout << "            r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "            05";       
    }   
    //space 201
    if (g1->value == 211)
    {
        cout << "  g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 211)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 211)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 211)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  G1";     
    }
    //space 22
    if (b1->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (g1->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (g2->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (g4->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 8)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  08";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 4                                                                       
    if (b1->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 4)
    {
        cout << "          r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "          04";     
    }   
    //space 202
    if (g1->value == 212)
    {
        cout << "    g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 212)
    {
        cout << "    g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 212)
    {
        cout << "    g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 212)
    {
        cout << "    g4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "    G2";       
    }
    //space 9
    if (b1->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    b1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (b2->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    b2";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (b3->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    b3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (b4->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    g4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (y1->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    y1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (y2->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "   y4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (r1->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 9)
    {
        cout << "    r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "    09";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 3                                                                       
    if (b1->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 3)
    {
        cout << "        r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "        03";       
    }   
    //space 203
    if (g1->value == 213)
    {
        cout << "      g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 213)
    {
        cout << "      g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 213)
    {
        cout << "      g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 213)
    {
        cout << "      g4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      G3";     
    }
    //space 10
    if (b1->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "     y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 10)
    {
        cout << "      r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      10";     
    }
    cout << "      ";
    if (y3 == british)
    {
        cout << "y3";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;                               
    //space 2                                                                       
    if (b1->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 2)
    {
        cout << "      r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      02";     
    }   
    //space 204
    if (g1->value == 214)
    {
        cout << "        g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 214)
    {
        cout << "        g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 214)
    {
        cout << "        g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 214)
    {
        cout << "        g4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "        G4";       
    }
    //space 11
    if (b1->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        r1"; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 11)
    {
        cout << "        r4"; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "        11";       
    }
    cout << "    ";
    if (y3 == british)
    {
        cout << "y3";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;   
    cout << "UK";
    //space 1                                                                       
    if (b1->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 1)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  01";     
    }   
    //space 12
    cout << "            ";
    if (b1->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          b2"; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          b4"; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          g1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          g2"; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          g4"; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          y1"; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          y4"; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          r2"; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 12)
    {
        cout << "          r4"; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "          12";     
    }
    cout << "  ";
    if (y2 == british)
    {
        cout << "y2";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;       
    //space 100
    if (b1 == italian)
    {
        cout << "b1";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    if (b1->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 100)
    {
        cout << "r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "BS";       
    }
    //space 101
    if (b1->value == 111)
    {
        cout << "  b1"; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 111)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 111)
    {
        cout << "  b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 111)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  B1";     
    }
    //space 102
    if (b1->value == 112)
    {
        cout << "b1"; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 112)
    {
        cout << "b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 112)
    {
        cout << "b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 112)
    {
        cout << "b4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "B2";       
    }
    //space 103
    if (b1->value == 113)
    {
        cout << "b1"; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 113)
    {
        cout << "b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 113)
    {
        cout << "b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 113)
    {
        cout << "b4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "B3";       
    }
    //space 104
    if (b1->value == 114)
    {
        cout << "b1"; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 114)
    {
        cout << "b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 114)
    {
        cout << "b3";
    }
    else if (b4->value == 114)
    {
        cout << "b4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "B4";       
    }
    cout << "      ";
    //space 304
    if (y1->value == 314)
    {
        cout << "y1"; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 314)
    {
        cout << "y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 314)
    {
        cout << "y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 314)
    {
        cout << "y4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Y4";       
    }
    //space 303
    if (y1->value == 313)
    {
        cout << "y1"; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 313)
    {
        cout << "y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 313)
    {
        cout << "y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 313)
    {
        cout << "y4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Y3";       
    }
    //space 302
    if (y1->value == 312)
    {
        cout << "y1"; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 312)
    {
        cout << "y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 312)
    {
        cout << "y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 312)
    {
        cout << "y4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Y2";       
    }
    //space 301
    if (y1->value == 311)
    {
        cout << "y1"; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 311)
    {
        cout << "y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 311)
    {
        cout << "y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 311)
    {
        cout << "y4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Y1";       
    }
    //space 300                                     
    if (b1->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 300)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  YS";     
    }
    if (y1 == british)
    {
        cout << "y1";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }   
    cout << endl;
    if (b2 == italian)
    {
        cout << "b2";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }   
    //space 24                                                                      
    if (b1->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 24)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  24";     
    }   
    //space 13
    cout << "            ";
    if (b1->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          b2"; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          y2"; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          y3";
    }
    else if (y4->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          r1"; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 13)
    {
        cout << "          r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "          13";     
    }
    cout << "  YE" << endl; 
    if (b3 == italian)
    {
        cout << "b3";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }   
    //space 23                                                                      
    if (b1->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 23)
    {
        cout << "    r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "    23";       
    }   
    //space 404
    if (r1->value == 414)
    {
        cout << "        r1"; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 414)
    {
        cout << "        r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 414)
    {
        cout << "        r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 414)
    {
        cout << "        r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "        R4";       
    }
    //space 14
    if (b1->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 14)
    {
        cout << "        r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "        14";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    if (b4 == italian)
    {
        cout << "b4";       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }   
    //space 22                                                                      
    if (b1->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 22)
    {
        cout << "      r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      22";     
    }   
    //space 403
    if (r1->value == 413)
    {
        cout << "      r1"; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 413)
    {
        cout << "      r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 413)
    {
        cout << "      r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 413)
    {
        cout << "     r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      R3";     
    }
    //space 15
    if (b1->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "     y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 15)
    {
        cout << "      r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "      15";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 21                                                                      
    if (b1->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 21)
    {
        cout << "          r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "          21";     
    }   
    //space 402
    if (r1->value == 412)
    {
        cout << "    g1"; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 412)
    {
        cout << "    g2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 412)
    {
        cout << "    g3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 412)
    {
        cout << "    g4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "    R2";       
    }
    //space 16
    if (b1->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "   y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 16)
    {
        cout << "    r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "    16";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 20                                                                      
    if (b1->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 20)
    {
        cout << "            r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "            20";       
    }   
    //space 401
    if (r1->value == 411)
    {
        cout << "  r1"; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 411)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 411)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 411)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  R1";     
    }
    //space 17
    if (b1->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 17)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  17";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 19
    if (b1->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              b1";
    }
    else if (b2->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              b2";
    }
    else if (b3->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              b3"; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              b4";
    }
    else if (g1->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              g1";
    }
    else if (g2->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              g2";
    }
    else if (g3->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              g3";
    }
    else if (g4->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              g4";
    }
    else if (y1->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              y1";
    }
    else if (y2->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              y2";
    }
    else if (y3->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              y3"; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              y4";
    }
    else if (r1->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              r1";
    }
    else if (r2->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              r2";
    }
    else if (r3->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              r3";
    }
    else if (r4->value == 19)
    {
        cout << "              r4";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "              19";     
    }   
    //space 18
    if (b1->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 18)
    {
        cout << "  r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "  18";
        cout << endl;       
    }
    //space 400
    if (b1->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                b1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b2->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                b2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b3->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                b3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (b4->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                b4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g1->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                g1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g2->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                g2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g3->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                g3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (g4->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                g4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y1->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                y1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y2->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                y2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y3->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                y3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (y4->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                y4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r1->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                r1";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r2->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                r2";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r3->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                r3";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else if (r4->value == 400)
    {
        cout << "                r4";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "                Italy";
        cout << endl;       
    }

    if (r1 == spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 != spanish && g4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r2";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r4";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r2r3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r3r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r2r4";
        cout << endl;
    }           
    if (r1 == spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r1r2r3r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r2";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r2r3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r2r4";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 == spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r2r3r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r3";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 == spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r3r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 == spanish)
    {
        cout << "                r4";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (r1 != spanish && r2 != spanish && r3 != spanish && r4 != spanish)
    {
        cout << "                  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Also, what's up with the quote ("The C++ language has two main components...")?

Answer (score 6):

There are a great number of things you could do to improve this program.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  I don't know that you've actually done that, but it's an alarmingly common thing for new C++ programmers to do.

### Use `const` where practical

It seems to me that printing the board shouldn't (and apparently doesn't) alter the underlying object.  If that's the case, it should be declared `const` to relay and enforce that fact.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

The current code contains these two lines:

```
//space 201
if (g1->value == 211)
```

It's not at all obvious whether 201 (mentioned in the comment) or 211 (actually used in the code) is the correct value, or exactly what it represents.  Better would be to use a named `const` value to avoid such confusion.

### Separate concerns

There are essentially two different things involved in printing the board.  The first is each individual data item and the second is the location on the screen.  Also, the board is symmetric and is, more or less, four different quadrants.  Each quadrant has a single country name.  If we consider each country's "home" positions as four independent positions, the middle-of-board positions (e.g. the ones you've got labelled "G1" through "G4") and the positions on one side of the diamond, there are 15 possible different positions in which a particular soldier might be located within each quadrant.  Since computers like base-16 numbers, let's say there are 16 and simply skip one. If we number each position with a 2-digit hex number and omit That layout looks like this:

```
                   State0
                  03020100

                     08
                   3e  09
                 3d  04  0a
               3c    05    0b         13
             3b      06      0c       12
           3a        07        0d     11
State3   39                      0e   10
       38  34353637      17161514  18
    30   2e                      19   State1
    31     2d        27        1a
    32       2c      26      1b
    33         2b    25    1c
                 2a  24  1d
                   29  1e
                     28

                  20212223
                   State2
```

Using this we can write a nice, neat print routine, but first let's look at objects.

### Use objects

You have a *board* and four *countries/players*, each with four *soldiers*.  It seems that you have an object for the board, but it's not clear that you have implemented objects for the other things.  Doing so would greatly simplify your code.  Here's one way to do that, using C++11 constructs and libraries:

```
class PlayBo {
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const PlayBo &pb);
    std::string pos(int location) const;
private:
    static constexpr int SoldierCount{4};
    static constexpr int CountryCount{4};
    struct Country {
        Country(std::string name, char letter, int offset) :
            name{name},
            prefix{letter},
            offset{offset},
            soldier{}
        {
            std::iota(soldier.begin(), soldier.end(), offset);
        }
        std::string name;
        char prefix;
        int offset;
        std::array<int, SoldierCount> soldier;
    };
    std::array<Country, CountryCount> players{{
        {"France", 'g', 0x00},
        {"Italy ", 'y', 0x10},
        {"  UK  ", 'b', 0x20},
        {"Spain ", 'r', 0x30},
    }};
};
```

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Use an `ostream operator<<` to print a class

Instead of using a named member function to print the class, I usually find it makes the object easier to use if instead we define an output stream operator.  In this case, a friend class declaration within the `PlayBo` class might look like this:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const PlayBo &pb);
```

Here's an implementation using the classes shown above:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const PlayBo &b)
{
    return out
    << "                   " << b.players[0].name << "\n"
    << "                  " << b.pos(0x03) << b.pos(0x02) << b.pos(0x01) << b.pos(0x00) << "\n"
    << "\n"
    << "                     " << b.pos(0x08) << "\n"
    << "                   " << b.pos(0x3e) << "  " << b.pos(0x09) << "\n"
    << "                 " << b.pos(0x3d) << "  " << b.pos(0x04) << "  " << b.pos(0x0a) << "\n"
    << "               " << b.pos(0x3c) << "    " << b.pos(0x05) << "    " << b.pos(0x0b) << "         " << b.pos(0x13) << "\n"
    << "             " << b.pos(0x3b) << "      " << b.pos(0x06) << "      " << b.pos(0x0c) << "       " << b.pos(0x12) << "\n"
    << "           " << b.pos(0x3a) << "        " << b.pos(0x07) << "        " << b.pos(0x0d) << "     " << b.pos(0x11) << "\n"
    << b.players[3].name << "   " << b.pos(0x39) << "                      " << b.pos(0x0e) << "   " << b.pos(0x10) << "\n"
    << "       " << b.pos(0x38) << "  " << b.pos(0x34) << b.pos(0x35) << b.pos(0x36) << b.pos(0x37) << "      " << b.pos(0x17) << b.pos(0x16) << b.pos(0x15) << b.pos(0x14) << "  " << b.pos(0x18) << "\n"
    << "    " << b.pos(0x30) << "   " << b.pos(0x2e) << "                      " << b.pos(0x19) << "   " << b.players[1].name << "\n"
    << "    " << b.pos(0x31) << "     " << b.pos(0x2d) << "        " << b.pos(0x27) << "        " << b.pos(0x1a) << "\n"
    << "    " << b.pos(0x32) << "       " << b.pos(0x2c) << "      " << b.pos(0x26) << "      " << b.pos(0x1b) << "\n"
    << "    " << b.pos(0x33) << "         " << b.pos(0x2b) << "    " << b.pos(0x25) << "    " << b.pos(0x1c) << "\n"
    << "                 " << b.pos(0x2a) << "  " << b.pos(0x24) << "  " << b.pos(0x1d) << "\n"
    << "                   " << b.pos(0x29) << "  " << b.pos(0x1e) << "\n"
    << "                     " << b.pos(0x28) << "\n"
    << "\n"
    << "                  " << b.pos(0x20) << b.pos(0x21) << b.pos(0x22) << b.pos(0x23) << "\n"
    << "                   " << b.players[2].name << "\n";
}
```

Each line in the function represents a line in the output to make it slightly easier to see what's going on.  This is not the neatest possible method to use, but it's considerably easier to see what's happening than in the original and it's much, much shorter.

Now all that remains is to implement the helper function which returns the string to be printed, given the location.  This is one way to do that:

```
std::string PlayBo::pos(int location) const
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    bool found = false;
    for (const auto &state: players) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SoldierCount; ++i) {
            if (state.soldier[i] == location) {
                ss << state.prefix << i;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        if ((location & 0xf) < 8) {
            ss << "  ";
        } else {
            ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << location;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

That function does a rather simple-minded linear search for each `soldier` location and prints either that soldier's designation or the appropriate string if the location is empty.  By numbering things cleverly, we can make the code easier to write.  In this case, only the empty places along the diamond are printed, while the starting places and the inside-the-diamond locations should be represented with spaces.  Note that all we need to do is look at the low four bits to determine aht classification.  That is, anything the is in the range of 0 through 7 should be spaces if the location is empty.  This keeps the code small and simple.

### Make sure to `#include` all required headers

This program apparently uses `std::cout` and a number of other things from `<iostream>` but doesn't show that `#include`.  To make it easier for reviewers to review, it's useful to explicitly put all required headers in the code to be reviewed.  For the rewritten version shown above, you'd need these:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>
```

### Testing

The code as presented doesn't appear to have been tested and contained some bugs.  To avoid that, testing is very useful.  Here's some extremely simple test code to exercise the printing function shown above.

```
int main() {
    PlayBo board;
    std::cout << board << "\n";
}
```

Here's the output that produces:

```
                   France
                  g3g2g1g0

                     08
                   3e  09
                 3d      0a
               3c          0b         y3
             3b              0c       y2
           3a                  0d     y1
Spain    39                      0e   y0
       38                          18
    r0   2e                      19   Italy 
    r1     2d                  1a
    r2       2c              1b
    r3         2b          1c
                 2a      1d
                   29  1e
                     28

                  b0b1b2b3
                     UK
```

I don't know if those positions or soldier designations are what you want, but with the revised code, those are trivial to change.

### Use a better random number generator

The code currently includes this line:

```
int roll = rand()%6 + 1;
```

Unless `RAND_MAX` is evenly divisible by 6 (and it's virtually certain **not** to be), then rather than an equal probability for all numbers 1 through 6, this will skew to the lower numbers.  In C++11, we can do much better:

```
#include <random>
class Die {
public:
    int operator()() { 
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,6);
        return dist(eng);
    }

private:
    static std::mt19937 eng;
};

std::mt19937 Die::eng{std::random_device{}()};
```

Now when you need a die roll, use the object instead of that.

```
int main()
{
    for (unsigned limit=30000000; limit; --limit) {
        Die{}();
    }
}
```

This generate 3 million die rolls and on my machine, it takes about 500ms.

Comment: I only reviewed what you posted and can't help you with parts of the program I haven't seen.

Answer (score 3):

Your first section:

```
if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "                g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "              g2g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "              g3g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "              g4g1";
    cout << endl;
}   
if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "            g3g2g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 == french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "            g4g3g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "            g4g2g1";
    cout << endl;
}           
if (g1 == french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "          g4g3g2g1";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "                g2";
    cout << endl;
}   
if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "              g3g2";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "              g4g2";
    cout << endl;
}   
if (g1 != french && g2 == french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "            g4g3g2";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "                g3";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 == french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "              g4g3";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 == french)
{
    cout << "                g4";
    cout << endl;
}
if (g1 != french && g2 != french && g3 != french && g4 != french)
{
    cout << "                  ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Can be greatly simplified if you take out the common bits.

```
std::cout << "            "; // This amount of space is always printed.
std::cout << ((g4 == french) ? "g4" : "  ");
std::cout << ((g3 == french) ? "g3" : "  ");
std::cout << ((g2 == french) ? "g2" : "  ");
std::cout << ((g1 == french) ? "g1" : "  ");
std::cout << "\n";   // prefer to use '\n' rather than std::endl
```

I hope that inspires you to simplify the rest of the code.

The next section is a classic example of when to use an array:

```
if (b1->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                b1";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (b2->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                b2";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (b3->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                b3";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (b4->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                b4";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (g1->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                g1";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (g2->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                g2";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (g3->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                g3";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (g4->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                g4";
    cout << endl;
}
else if (y1->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                y1";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (y2->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                y2";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (y3->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                y3";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (y4->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                y4";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (r1->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                r1";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (r2->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                r2";
    cout << endl;
}
else if (r3->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                r3";
    cout << endl; 
}
else if (r4->value == 200)
{
    cout << "                r4";
    cout << endl; 
}
else
{
    cout << "                GS";
    cout << endl;       
}
```

You have 16 soldiers. Four soldiers from each country.

```
 b1, b2, b3, b4
 g1, g2, g3, g4
 y1, y2, y3, y4
 r1, r2, r3, r4
```

If you put this in an array. Then use the country number as the first index and the soldier number as the second index. Then you can use a simple loop to check each of the soldiers.

```
  TypeForSoldier   data[4][4]; // instead of b1,b2, ..... r3,r4
  char             countryLetter[] = {'b', 'g', 'y', 'r'};

  for(int country = 0; country < 4; ++country) {
      for(int soldier = 0; soldier < 4; ++soldier) {
          if (data[country][soldier]->value == 200) {
              std::cout << "                "
                        << countryLetter[country]
                        << soldier
                        << "\n";
              break;
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, read "[Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)".
2. Next, only flush your stream manually when you have to. Not only is it more verbose, but it also kills performance. So, no throwing around `std::endl`.
3. Consider changing your data-structure:
   Make it a single array of length N = #board_fields + #home_fields = 4 * 6 + 4 * 4
   Each field stores whether it's empty (0 for empty home-fields, 1-24 for board-fields) or which of the 4 * 4 (25-40) pieces are there.

   Next, have an array mapping from that id to a human-readable abbreviation.

   And as a final part, use `sprintf` or some other printing function to create your whole map in one go.

```
const static char names[][4] = {
    "  ",
    "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12",
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
    "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4",
    "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"
};
char field[4*6+4*4];

void init_board() {
    std::itoa(std::begin(field), std::end(field), 1);
}

void print_board() {
    const char format[] =
        "                France\n"
        "          %s%s%s%s\n"
        ...;
    char out[sizeof(format)];
    #define X(n) names[field[n]]
    sprintf(out, format, X(24), X(25), X(26), X(27), ...);
    #undef X
    std::cout << out;
}
```